# Webservices not working with SSL certificate

Tags: ssl-certificate, tls1.2

We have hosted our web service in Windows Server 2022. When we invoke the web service with an SSL certificate from the client application (Desktop application, .Net 4.5), it's not working.

When we invoke web service without an SSL certificate, it's working fine.

We have added this line (System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls Or SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 Or SecurityProtocolType.Tls12) in client application and invoked the webservices, its working fine.

My question is, how to make the program work without adding the  (System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls Or SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 Or SecurityProtocolType.Tls12) line ?

Is there any option in server side to make webservice work without changeing the client program?